# Count days and stop count if status is completed

Tags: laravel, date, datetime, laravel-5

I am trying to count the number of days between two dates and when the `status == complete` the count of days stops.

```php
if ($this->status == 'COMPLETED') {
    $now = Carbon::now();
    $start_date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $this->start_date);
    $this->start_date_to_current_date = $start_date->diffInDays($now, true);
}
```

But the problem is, the days still continues to count and increment. how can I can make the counting stop ?

Comment: What do you mean "the days still continues to count and increment"?

Comment: i mean the days keep counting even if the status is completed
like for example the value is 1 then the next day it becomes 2.

Comment: And you want it to only happen once?

Comment: yes if the initial value is 1 i want the counting of days stop.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `start_date_to_current_date` is nullable, you can just check if the field has already been set by doing something similar to below:

```php
if ($this->status === null && $this->status === 'COMPLETED') {
    $now = Carbon::now();
    $start_date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $this->start_date);
    $this->start_date_to_current_date = $start_date->diffInDays($now, true);
}
```

That way, it will only run a single time, and once it's set it won't be updated when the code re-runs.

Comment: ive tried the method that you've suggested but the value turns into 0. i dont know why :/